# Java building an API, how to do different file handling based on file name?

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

I've been tasked to build an API that handles files in java. It is the first time I build the API in java. So now I have two problems.

Problem number 1: 
My question is, how to do different file handling based on file name?
There are two types of files and the name of the file is such 162211_abFile.txt and the other file is 33232_abcTextFile.txt so the question is how do I get my api to run a particular method based on it is .... _abFile or .... _abcTextFile.

Problem number 2: 
I have a couple of methods in another class that I need to call how do I do it in the most efficient manner? After I read the file ie.

This is my try when i read the files.

```
try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("162211_abFile.txt"));
        String line = null;
```

I hope I have explained well and that you understood my problem.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit nr 1:**

The method signatures

```
public interface PaymentReceiver {

public void startPaymentBundle(String accountNumber, Date paymentDate, String currency);

public void payment(BigDecimal amount, String reference);

public void endPaymentBundle();
```

}

Comment: Are you asking how to do different file handling based on file name?

Comment: Yes, sorry for bad explanation. :(

The numbers in the name are dynamic and the letters are static. So the numbers will be different for every day.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what an API is?  Your question does not make much sense... if you're trying to make an API, show us some interface method signatures.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx please se the updated question for method signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question, you can accomplish it using [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

If the files follow the format [numbers]_[filename].txt you can do the following:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+_(\\w+)\\.txt");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("33232_abcTextFile.txt");
    if (m.matches()) {
        if (m.group(1).equals("abFile")) {
            // Do something
        } else if (m.group(1).equals("abcTextFile")) {
            // Do something else
        } else {
            // Unknown filename, handle it
        }
    } else {
        // Unknown file format, handle it
    }
```

The pattern, the string fed to *Pattern.compile*, here is going to match 1 or more digits, followed by an underscore, followed 1 or more characters, followed by .txt.

If there should be more file names to consider in the future, you can just to ad another else if clause that handles that file name.

Comment: I like your solution can you help me with the other one? @Arclight